# Android Marshmallow breaks old layout

Tags: android, android-layout

My app was first developed for Android 2.3, but has been updated *many* times and currently targets V21. So I was surprised when my Nexus 5 received the Marshmallow update and found that a critical feature of my app was broken. I have a screen with a line at the top where I want two buttons at the far right and an EditText box (for search text) filling up the remainder of the screen to the left. This was my first app and I was unclear about various layout techniques, but from Android 2.3 to 5.1 this code has continued to work:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/upper_detail_section"
    android:elevation="@dimen/upper_elevation"
>
    <Button android:id="@+id/sort"
        style="@style/large_cust_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/sort"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/clear"
        style="@style/large_cust_btn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sort"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:text="@string/clear"
    />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/lookup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/clear"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/item_search_hint"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="textFilter"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Bringing this screen up in Android 6.0, the buttons are there but the EditText field completely disappears! Knowing what I know now it turned out to be a simple fix using a LinearLayout and weighting:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/upper_detail_section"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:elevation="@dimen/upper_elevation"
    >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/lookup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/item_search_hint"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="textFilter"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/clear"
        style="@style/large_cust_btn"
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:onClick="clearClicked"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/sort"
        style="@style/large_cust_btn"
        android:text="@string/sort"
        android:onClick="sortClicked"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

So all is well now and I'm updating the store with a new APK, but I thought I'd warn people that some layout tricks that used to work may now be broken.

Comment: This would be better handled as a question and an answer, [to fit the site structure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you do that, you might also consider before-and-after screenshots, as it is difficult to understand what "broken" really means in this context.

Comment: I assume `large_cust_btn` defines layout_width and layout_height?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot that detail. By "broken" I mean that the EditText field did not appear on the screen. The buttons were visible as expected, but there was only blank space to the left of them. Also, the large_cust_button style defines a width & height (e.g., wrap_content with some margins).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding and reproducing your problem correctly, it's quite simple to fix your issues with `RelativeLayout` as well. Marshmallow only handles a width of `match_parent` differently. So just set it to something else like with the `LinearLayout` and alignParentLeft to `true`:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/lookup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    [...] />
```

This yielded the same layout for me like in pre Marshmallow.